# A question on the proof of Cheeger-Colding's second paper

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Reading the paper *On the structure of spaces with ricci curvature bounded below II* by Cheeger and Colding, I have trouble understanding the proof of Theorem 3.7. In the last part of the proof, they said that combining Lemma 3.1 with $$\limsup_{i\rightarrow \infty}Vol_{i}(A_{i,\eta,\varepsilon+\psi})\leq \nu(A_{\eta,\varepsilon+\psi}),$$ we can get $$Vol(B_d(m_i))-\Psi(\eta|\varepsilon,\psi,n)\leq Vol_i(A_{i,\eta,\varepsilon+\psi}).$$ How can this be true?

Comment: One may get more of a response to this question if more information is supplied (e.g. a link to the paper, an explanation of the notation, and the context of the argument).

Comment: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214459974

Comment: In the problem, $\{(Y,y,\nu)\}$ is the convergence of $\{(M_i,m_i,Vol_i)\}$ in the sense of Gromov-Hausdorff distance, where $\nu$ and $Vol_i$ are volume forms with respect to $Y$ and $M_i$. $\Psi(\eta|\varepsilon,\psi,n)$ is a non-negative function which is $0$ while $\eta$ tends to $0$. In my opinion, the last equation is a contradiction to the result of the lemma3.1 i.e. if every minimal geodesic connecting $y_1$ and $y_2$ intersects $B$, then there exists positive number $c$ such that $c\leq \sum_j r_j^{-1}\nu(B_{r_j}(w_j))$.

Comment: The paper in your link does not have a Theorem 3.7 or a Lemma 3.1.   I suggest re-editing your question to add significantly more detail, and to quote relevant parts the paper (by screenshot if necessary).

Comment: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214342145

Comment: Sorry to provide the wrong link. Here is the right version.

Comment: From a quick glance at the paper, it appears that the second inequality is not a consequence of the first, but is simply a direct consequence of (the contrapositive of) Lemma 3.1, applied to the $\epsilon+\psi$-neighbourhood of $E_{\eta,i}$.